# Dynamically create entities at runtime - Spring boot, hibernate, Java or Grails with Gorm orm?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, backend

My CRM application supports multiple clients where clients are allowed to create/update schema at runtime.

So, the question is:- how to create ORM entities at runtime without restarting the server?

Kindly suggest if any framework has already solved this use-case with multi-tenant support.

Is it possible by some dynamic programming like groovy, grails and gorm?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible by some dynamic programming like groovy, grails and
>   gorm?

It may be possible with some ORM.  If you are using Hibernate, as a practical matter I think the answer is "no".  The session factory is immutable.  From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html:

> The internal state of a SessionFactory is immutable. Once it is
>   created this internal state is set. This internal state includes all
>   of the metadata about Object/Relational Mapping.

If you are using another ORM tool then the details will depend on which ORM tool you are using.